# Не отображается карта

Tags: google-maps-api, angular2

Подскажите пожалуйста где искать ошибку.

Я использую angular2 + AGM module. установил AGM так:

```
npm install @agm/core --save
```

Подключил в app.module.ts так:

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
        AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
          apiKey: 'AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU'
        })    
  ],
```

tpl:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

компонент:

```
  lat: number = 51.678418;
  lng: number = 7.809007;
```

css:

```
agm-map {
  height: 300px;
}
```

Но в результате карта в браузере появляется на долю секунды, а затем отображается следующее:

```
При загрузке Google Карт на этой странице возникла проблема. Подробности вы найдете в консоли JavaScript.
```

При этом консоль выводит такое сообщение об ошибке:

```
Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: http://localhost:4200/
```

Я пробовал перенести build с локалхоста на реальный [хостинг](https://zlodiak.github.io/ng2/maps/1_agm/). Но ничего не изменилось.

Непонятно что делать с этой проблемой и в чём она вообще заключается...

Comment: Видимо, при регистрации вашего `apiKey`(кстати, надеюсь он не реальный) вы не указали `url` сайта, на котором будут работать ваши карты.

Comment: Вы правы. Я использовал не свой apiKey, а он, видимо, был с ограничениями